# 1980s (possibly) Cartoon movie, Oil workers find a magic mask when drilling for oil

Tags: story-identification, magic, robots, cartoon

I am looking for a movie I saw when I was a kid, all I can remember is some oil workers drilling for oil then an old magic mask causing an earthquake and rising out of the ground, the next part I remember is when some humans get into this car/robot thing which is in an underground tunnel half filled with lava, the vehicle/robot is lava proof and they survive, something may be chasing them.
Sorry for being so vague but I can't remember anything more, it was a cartoon and it might have been a tv show but I THINK it was a movie, the animation looked like 1980s but I could be wrong

Comment: Roughly when did you watch it?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't simply "The Mask Animated Series"?

Comment: I watched it roughly between 2004 - 2006 but the animation looked very 80s if my memory is correct.

Comment: It's not the mask animated series, definitely a different plot. The mask itself looked to be an ancient tribal mask or something like that if my memory is correct again, it rose out of the ground causing an earthquake while some men were drilling for oil in the desert

Comment: A (very) long-shot, but the description reminds me of the original Transformers cartoon from the 80s. There was at least one episode that involved oil-drilling, earthquakes, and a half-robot half-car, but no specific episode that matches your description.

Comment: My first thought was an episode from the Sunbow G.I. Joe tv series in the mid-80's, they had some psi-type episodes with mind control and ancient powers and so on, but I don't remember an episode like that.

Comment: Could you give me the name of that episode of transformers or give me a link to it? In the underground tunnel it was half filled with lava I think and then i think some humans got into this robot or car thing that was resistant to the lava and they escaped, that is where my memory ends.

Comment: im not sure if it was G.I Joe, it seems more like transformers to me personally but i could be wrong, it was years ago after all :)

Comment: Other than the 'ancient' part, it sounds like MASK
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M.A.S.K._(TV_series)